# When clicked in parent's html, call child method in Angular 2/Ionic

Tags: html, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, angular2-directives

I face this situation for many hours and i can't find an proper answer. I'm using angular 2 with ionic 2.

I have **1 page** (HomePage - **home.ts**, **home.html**)

and **1 component** (GoogleMaps, **google-maps.ts**, **google-maps.html**)

In **home.html** i have this:

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-buttons end>
      <button ion-button (click)="findMyLocation()">Find</button>
    </ion-buttons> 
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
```

In **google-maps.ts** i have findMyLocation method but i don't know how to trigger it in my component from home.html (parent's page)

Full code here: http://plnkr.co/edit/Qcy4BKHgC1GBMrLJO7lj

The error is: Cannot read property 'findMyLocation' of undefined

**EDIT:** i've found one way with this code in **home.ts**, but i hope to be another one much easier? There is?

```
@ViewChild(GoogleMaps) gmap: GoogleMaps;

  findMyLocation(){
    this.gmap.findMyLocation();
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
<google-maps #googlemaps></google-maps>
```

And then use it like that:

```
<button ion-button (click)="googlemaps.findMyLocation()">Find</button>
```

I tried it with a simple example and it worked. I haven't found anything in the docs so far, so I can't tell you how exactly this works. It seems like the # creates a local variable with a reference to your component, which you can then use within the current scope.

Comment: Thank's! This is what i'm looking for.